# How to convert Rows into Columns in Informix 12.10

Tags: sql, pivot, informix

| Localcol | SA_Device A | SA_Device B | SA_Device C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | 16 | 17 | 18 |

| Localcol | AA_Device A | AA_Device B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | 34 | 43 |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | 45 | 46 |

I need to join these 2 tables into one and show it as below format.

| Localcol | Device | SA | AA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | Device A | 12 | 34 |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | Device B | 13 | 43 |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | Device C | 14 | NA |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | Device A | 16 | 45 |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | Device B | 17 | 46 |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | Device C | 18 | NA |

Please help me to solve this case in Informix 12.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I'm thinking you should unpivot each table and then join them:

```
select coalesce(t2.localcol, t1.localcol) as localcol,
       coalesce(t2.device, t1.device) as device,
       t1.SA, t2.AA
from (select Localcol, 'A' as device, AA_Device_A as AA
      from table2 t2
      union all
      select Localcol, 'B' as device, AA_Device_B
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 full join
     (select Localcol, 'A' as device, SA_Device_A as SA
      from table2 t1
      union all
      select Localcol, 'B' as device, SA_Device_B as SA
      from table2 t1
      union all
      select Localcol, 'C' as device, SA_Device_B as SA
      from table2 t1
     ) t1
     on t1.localcol = t2.localcol and t1.device = t2.device
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `COALESCE` is not part of Informix 12.10 (12.10.FC6 tested), though it is present in Informix 14.10 (14.10.FC1 tested).  However, the Oracle-compatible NVL function is present in 12.10 (same version tested) which does essentially the same job.  Simply change `COALESCE` to `NVL` throughout.

Comment: IBM has it documented as part of 12.1:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=expressions-coalesce-function.

Comment: That's why I included the tested version information — it probably got added after 12.10.FC6, then (I think the current release is 12.10.FC14 or 12.10.FC15, IIRC).  And it's also why I usually request the version information when people ask a question.